# How to install CakePHP plugin for PHP IDE Netbeans 7.2

Tags: cakephp, plugins, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I have the PHP IDE version of NetBeans 7.2 and have installed the plugin successfully (it is shown as enabled in the plugins list and appears in the project properties). However, nowhere do I see a place to select the framework as shown in the download page (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44579). When creating a new IDE there is no step 4, just 1,2, and 3...so obviously something is missing. Is there a dependent plugin I need or maybe I need the full, huge version of NetBeans?

I am using Windows 7, PHP 5.3, CakePHP 2.1.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin was working correctly, however it requires that there only be 1 app in the project folder in the same directory as the CakePHP lib folder.  The NetBeans project folder is not the 'app' folder that contains the Controllers and Views folders, instead it must be the folder that contains the app and lib folders.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to NetBeans' main menu `Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins`. Choose the plugin you want and install it.